# I am not able to Warp div tag through jquery Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery

I am trying to insert div tag in the `div.accordion-template` just after each `h1` tag. I have updated my below jquery code in `app.js`

```
// Accordions
var $accordion = $j('div.accordion-template');
$accordion.find('h1').each(function () {
    var $this = $j(this);
    $this.nextUntil('h1').wrapAll('<div class="accordion-content"></div>');
});

$accordion.find('div.accordion-content').hide()

$accordion.on('click', 'h1', function () {
    $this = $j(this);
    $this.toggleClass('open');
    $this.next('div.accordion-content').slideToggle();
});
```

And below is my HTML output in the browser:

```
<div class="accordion-template">
    <h1>Long Tradition</h1>
    <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
    <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
    <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
    <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
    <h1>Technology at your Service</h1>
    <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
    <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
    <h1>Price Match Guarantee</h1>
    <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
    <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
    <h1>Customer Service</h1>
    <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
    <p>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.</p>
</div>
```

I am not able to figure out why I am not able to create `accordion-content` div.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about HTML and JS.

Comment: are you getting any JS console error ?

Comment: I didn't get any JS console error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place `JS` code inside `jQuery(document).ready`, like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Accordions
    var $accordion = $j('div.accordion-template');
    $accordion.find('h1').each(function(){
        var $this = $j(this);
        $this.nextUntil('h1').wrapAll('<div class="accordion-content"></div>');
    });

    $accordion.find('div.accordion-content').hide()

    $accordion.on('click', 'h1', function(){
        $this = $j(this);
        $this.toggleClass('open');
        $this.next('div.accordion-content').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: @VaibhavDass: does this solve your issue ?

Comment: I didn't try this code. However I have placed the same code in the same phtml file and it started working. Thanks